# AWS cloudwatch: logs are getting created in different log streams for the single API hit

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

We are making use of AWS Lambda and have configured cloudwatch for logging. There is a cron job running every 5 minutes which is triggering the lambda function. The logs that are generated for the hit are getting created in different log streams. For reference, please check the image attached here:

[image]

So, let's say there is an API hit at 11:45, then for checking the logs I have to go through the log streams having last event time 2022-05-05 11:43:10 (UTC+05:30) , 2022-05-05 11:43:00 (UTC+05:30), 2022-05-05 11:38:11 (UTC+05:30) and 2022-05-05 11:38:02 (UTC+05:30) and so on. The reason is, for a single hit logs are getting created in different log streams. Some of the logs are in first log stream, some are in second, a few are in third one. Previously, all the logs were created in single log stream corresponding to a single hit. Is there anything that can be done to avoid this? as this makes debugging a time taking process.

Answer (score 1):

This is how Lambda works: each Lambda execution environment gets its own log stream. If you need to look at logs across log streams, then the best "built-in" solution is [CloudWatch Logs Insights](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/AnalyzingLogData.html), which works at the log-group level.

Update: [this document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtime-environment.html) describes the Lambda execution environment, and the conditions that cause creation/destruction of an environment.

Comment: As I mentioned, the cron executed only once. For a single execution I am getting logs in three different log streams.

Comment: Also, as mentioned by you in above answer I have tried cloudwatch log insights and it is giving perfect results, but the question is why cloudwatch logs aren't created in an accumulated manner in a log stream for a single hit?

Comment: @AvaniKhabiya - in your question you say there's a cron running every 5 minutes, and in your comment you say that it executed only once. Clearly, it's not executing only once, because you have multiple log streams.

Comment: As for why each Lambda execution environment gets its own log stream, you'll have to find the AWS engineer that chose that behavior. It would just be speculation on my part (but based on experience with concurrent operations, I can tell you that it makes logs _much_ more readable if each operation has its own log stream).

Comment: The cron executed only once at a particular time and I am getting logs for the same in multiple log streams. Is it clear now?

Comment: Also, I am not concerned about the logs of next hit that will come after 5 minutes, they may or may not be created in separate log stream. I am just concerned about the logs created for a single iteration of the cron. @Parsifal

Comment: If you're getting multiple log streams, then there are multiple Lambdas being invoked. If you only expect one to be invoked, then you need to figure out why that's happening. One good way to start debugging is to print the invocation event as the first step of running the Lambda.